# Why is Android Studio deleting my codeStyleSettings, runConfiguration and renaming the project upon first time open?

Tags: android-studio

So I'm cloning a projet I have to a new folder with a different name than the name of the repo. So the clone command is something like this:

`git clone --recursive git@example.github.io:/my-repo other-folder-name`

After the first time I open it in Android Studio 1.4.1 the following files are changed:

```
modified:   .idea/.name
deleted:    .idea/codeStyleSettings.xml
deleted:    .idea/dictionaries/fronilse.xml
deleted:    .idea/encodings.xml
modified:   .idea/gradle.xml
modified:   .idea/inspectionProfiles/Project_Default.xml
modified:   .idea/misc.xml
deleted:    .idea/runConfigurations/I_Tests.xml
deleted:    .idea/runConfigurations/JTestsVG.xml
deleted:    .idea/runConfigurations/U_Tests.xml
deleted:    .idea/runConfigurations/VG.xml
deleted:    .idea/scopes/scope_settings.xml
modified:   .idea/vcs.xml
```

What's going on? Why does it delete my run configurations and code style settings? Why does it rename my project (in the `.name` file, the project is renamed to the same name as the folder). Am I not allowed to call the folder whatever I want?

So if I use the same folder name as the repo, no changes are done. The easiest solution is to just go with that of course, but I'm wondering if this is intended functionality or if I should maybe post an issue?

**edit:** Actually I've managed to reproduce the error even when using the original folder name

Comment: have you found a fix to the problem yet?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the `codeStyle/` directory getting deleted by Android Studio after cloning the repo. I don't know how to prevent that from happening, but a simple `git reset --hard HEAD` at your project's root will revert any modification made by Android Studio to your files.

However, beware that Android Studio *will have* to modify some files so that it can understand and remember how to read your project. Those machine-specific files, like `gradle.xml`, shouldn't be added to Git because they're often auto-generated and can change at anytime. See [this article](https://proandroiddev.com/deep-dive-into-idea-folder-in-android-studio-53f867cf7b70) to learn more about the `.idea/` directory.

Comment: Link for article now broken

Comment: @cking24343 https://web.archive.org/web/20201109005421/https://proandroiddev.com/deep-dive-into-idea-folder-in-android-studio-53f867cf7b70?gi=5df09e7ddb50 - Make sure to disable JavaScript via DevTools otherwise you'll get a blank page because of Medium's JS.